# File Byte Array Encryption corrupt the file except Text Document

Tags: c#, encryption, arrays

I made a simple file binary encrypt/decrypt and it works perfectly for any text document.
But when I encrypt and decrypt image / word document file, the file corrupt.
I don't understand why this happen.

This is my code to get the file byte array.

```
byte[] b = null;

            using (System.IO.FileStream fr = new System.IO.FileStream(this.txtFile.Text, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (System.IO.BinaryReader br = new System.IO.BinaryReader(fr))
                {
                    b = br.ReadBytes((int)fr.Length);
                }
            }
```

And this is how I write all the bytes back.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, b);
```

Can someone explain to me why?

Edit : This is my Encrypt/Decrypt code.
Sorry if its messy, I'm new to cryptograph.

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
        {
            if (keyIndex >= key.Length)
            {
                keyIndex = 0;
            }

            string fileBIN = Convert.ToString(b[i], 2);
            string keyBIN = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToChar(key[keyIndex])), 2);
            string newBIN = string.Empty;

            keyIndex += 1;

            if (fileBIN.Length > keyBIN.Length)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < Math.Abs(fileBIN.Length - keyBIN.Length); x++) { keyBIN = "0" + keyBIN; x -= 1; }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < Math.Abs(fileBIN.Length - keyBIN.Length); x++) { fileBIN = "0" + fileBIN; x -= 1; }
            }

            if (fileBIN == keyBIN)
            {
                newBIN = fileBIN;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < fileBIN.Length; x++)
                {
                    if (fileBIN.Substring(x, 1).ToString() == keyBIN.Substring(x, 1).ToString()) { newBIN += "0"; }
                    else { newBIN += "1"; }
                }
            }

            b[i] = Convert.ToByte(newBIN, 2);
        }
```

Comment: show your encryption/decryption code in question

Comment: I added my encryption code, according to my lecturer, it is vernam cipher that change binary to 0 if same and 1 if different. If both binary is the same, then I won't change it cause the result will be all zero.

Comment: Can you actually post your working solution, so that we can test the output for ourselves?

Comment: Where can I upload the project?